Laptop freezes with *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request
So my laptop will just freeze randomly (new laptop as well intel core ultra 7 running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS) I noticed these when I ran: journalctl -p err - the render error corresponds to the time when it fails but not sure anyone has encountered this problem
  Dec 02 14:02:59 ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 40
    Dec 02 14:02:59 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: DMAR: QI HEAD: Invalidation Wait qw0 = 0x200000025, qw1 = 0x1002c1634
    Dec 02 14:02:59 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: DMAR: QI PRIOR: Device-TLB Invalidation qw0 = 0x10001000000003, qw1 = 0x7ffffffffffff001
    Dec 02 14:02:59 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: GUC: TLB invalidation response timed out for seqno 1225766
    Dec 02 14:02:59 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.
    Dec 02 14:03:00 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.
    Dec 02 14:03:00 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.
    Dec 02 14:03:01 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.
    Dec 02 14:03:01 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: GUC: TLB invalidation response timed out for seqno 1225767
    Dec 02 14:03:02 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.
    Dec 02 14:03:02 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: DMAR: VT-d detected Invalidation Time-out Error: SID 10
    Dec 02 14:03:02 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 40
    Dec 02 14:03:02 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: DMAR: QI HEAD: Invalidation Wait qw0 = 0x200000025, qw1 = 0x1002c1644
    Dec 02 14:03:02 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: DMAR: QI PRIOR: Device-TLB Invalidation qw0 = 0x10001000000003, qw1 = 0x7ffffffffffff001
    Dec 02 14:03:02 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.
    Dec 02 14:03:03 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.
    Dec 02 14:03:03 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* gt: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.
    Dec 02 14:03:04 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: GUC: TLB invalidation response timed out for seqno 1225768
    Dec 02 14:03:04 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.
    Dec 02 14:03:05 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* gt: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.
    Dec 02 14:03:05 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: DMAR: VT-d detected Invalidation Time-out Error: SID 10
    Dec 02 14:03:05 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: DMAR: QI HEAD: Invalidation Wait qw0 = 0x200000025, qw1 = 0x1002c1654
    Dec 02 14:03:05 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 40
    Dec 02 14:03:05 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: DMAR: QI PRIOR: Device-TLB Invalidation qw0 = 0x10001000000003, qw1 = 0x7ffffffffffff001
    Dec 02 14:03:05 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.
    Dec 02 14:03:06 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* gt: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.
    Dec 02 14:03:06 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: GUC: TLB invalidation response timed out for seqno 1225769
    Dec 02 14:03:06 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.
    Dec 02 14:03:07 -ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-12 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* gt: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.


Update Intel Graphics Drivers: Sometimes, the default drivers may not be the most stable. You can try updating to the latest Intel graphics drivers. Follow the instructions on the Intel Graphics for Linux website to add the repository and install the latest drivers.
Disable VT-d: If you do not need VT-d for your work, you can try disabling it in the BIOS settings. To do this:
    Navigate to the Security tab and find the Virtualization section.
    Disable Intel VT-d and save the changes.
    Reboot your system and check if the issue persists.


this is one of the suggestion from Lenovo in case it helps anyone
